# Crash when reloading collectionView frequently

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

In an iOs app I am using a collection view that will frequently be update when the user taps on a cell in a different collectionView that is onscreen. The collection view receives data one row at a time and reloads the collectionView.

Here is the code in the selection:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (collectionView == self.datePickerCollectionView) {


        [[self.PickerCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.crtDelta inSection:0]] setSelected:NO];

        if (self.crtDelta == indexPath.item) {
            // in case the user taps on the day he allready is on
            // don't do anything
            return;
        }

        self.crtDelta = indexPath.item;

            [self.attriburesRectDict removeAllObjects];
            [self.CollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
            [self.CollectionView reloadData];
            [self.TableView reloadData];
            self.DataDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
      }

// get data from web manager here
}
```

As you can see the data dictionarys are reset.

```
- (void)didReceiveDataForSection:(NSInteger)section withDataArray:(NSArray*)data andRectsArray:(NSArray*)rects
{
   self.programsDict[@(index)] = data;
    self.attriburesRectDict[@(index)] = rects;
   [self.programsCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

Here 1 row of data is received and added to the relevant dictionaries for use.
This is the layout code:

```
@interface MultipleLineLayout()

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger numRows;

@end


@implementation MultipleLineLayout {
    CGFloat itemHeight;
}

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
        itemHeight = 0.0;
    }
    return self;
}

-(CGSize)collectionViewContentSize {
    NSInteger xSize = self.contentSizeWidth;
    NSInteger ySize = [self.collectionView numberOfSections] * (itemHeight + PROGRAMS_CELL_SPACING);
    return CGSizeMake(xSize, ySize);
}

-(void)prepareLayout
{
    [super prepareLayout];
    [self.collectionView setBounces:NO];
    if (self.collectionView) {
        self.numRows = [self.collectionView numberOfSections];
    }
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *a = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:path];
    a.frame = [self.dataSource rectForAttributesForRow:path.row inSection:path.section];
    return a;
}

-(NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSMutableArray* attributes = [NSMutableArray array];
    if (itemHeight == 0.0) {
        itemHeight = [self.dataSource heightOfProgramCell];
    }

    NSUInteger startRow = floorf(rect.origin.y / itemHeight);
    NSUInteger endRow =   ceilf(CGRectGetMaxY(rect) / (CGFloat)itemHeight);
    if (endRow >= self.numRows) {
        endRow = self.numRows ;
    }
    for (NSUInteger r = startRow; r < endRow; r++)
    {
        NSUInteger noProgs = [self.dataSource numberOfElementsInSection:r];
        for (NSUInteger c = 0; c <noProgs; c++)
        {
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* o = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:c inSection:r]];

            if(o.size.width > 0) {
                [attributes addObject:o];
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return attributes;
}

- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

The problem is that sometimes if you switch the data (taps on the collection view code shown in 1st code snippet) very frequently (like 2 taps a second) the app crashes:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UICollectionViewData.m:341
2014-08-21 12:14:33.052 du View[365:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0x18c1be10> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2dd4cf4b 0x385c36af 0x2dd4ce25 0x2e6f4fe3 0x3051c953 0x3051c063 0x3051b8c7 0x304bfda3 0x30146c6b 0x3014247b 0x3014230d 0x30141d1f 0x30141b2f 0x3013b85d 0x2dd181cd 0x2dd15b71 0x2dd15eb3 0x2dc80c27 0x2dc80a0b 0x32981283 0x30524049 0x14c529 0x38acbab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I believe this is some sort of interference between the reloads in the didSelectCell and the reload in the did receive data. I do cancel all data requests when switching but somehow after a while it seems the collection view enters this confused state and crashes.

How can I prevent this crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The problem was in numberOfCellsInSection. There I was returning 0 if no data was available, but apparently that method isn't called often enough so when data was available it was still expecting 0. Changed that to return 100 and haven't seen the crash anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient and performant to `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` instead of reloading the whole view when only a single view gets added at a time, also it will prevent weird scrolling artifacts.

Comment: I agree!  Or, maybe do a bunch of processing, then reload the whole thing once. Not sure who gave you the thumbs down, but I've countered that.  Especially since I really don't like his "solution". :-)